# How to set Slider control Value from ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit with JavaScript function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How to set Slider control Value from ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit with JavaScript function?
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is!  You have to set the value of `asp:TextBox` control that's associated with your `SliderExtender` to the value that you want.  So for this ASP markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sliderBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:SliderExtender ID="sliderBox_SliderExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" 
    Maximum="100" Minimum="0" TargetControlID="sliderBox">
</asp:SliderExtender>
<asp:Button ID="incButton" runat="server" Text="incrementSlider" 
    onclientclick="change();" />
```

Which is basically:

1. an `asp:TextBox` named sliderBox (for the `SliderExtender` to use)
2. an `asp:SliderExtender` sliderBox_SliderExtender (with basically
   default values)
3. an `asp:Button` named incButton.  This has an `onClientClick` property that calls the `change()` javascript function

And here is the `change()` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() {
        document.getElementById("sliderBox").value += 10;
    }
</script>
```

The `change()` function increments the value in the `asp:TextBox` control by 10, thus increasing the sliders position each time you click the button.

Comment: That script works because 'incButton' is ASP button so post back happens on click after text box value is set client-side. If you add 'return false;' to 'change' function to prevent postback position won't change. Way I did it purely client-side was to find 'slider' div and set it's 'style.left' value. To get correct position you have to divine length of line by max value and multiply it by step (10 in that case).

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your concern / feedback, @PrzemG.  But it seems to me that, instead of doing all that with returning false, you could just use a different (client-side) control.  Rather than trying to prevent the postback, use a link with href="#", and handle it's click event.

Comment: My point is that changing 'value' of sliderBox element client-side does not have visual effect on the page until you do postback. If you change asp:Button to <a> with href="#" it won't work - slider won't move. Additionally element's value is text so '+10' appends string '10' to existing string so if existing value is 30 it is changed to 3010 not to 40.