# Specify custom values for AjaxControlToolkit slider extender

Tags: javascript, slider, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the `MultiHandleSliderExtender` from AjaxControlToolkit. I was looking for a way to specify custom values for the slider extender:

```
<act:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="mseTimeline" runat="server" BoundControlID="lblSlider"
    Minimum="1600" Maximum="1680" TooltipText="Slide across timeline"
    TargetControlID="ebSlider" Decimals="0"
    RaiseChangeOnlyOnMouseUp="true" OnClientDragEnd="scrollToYear">
</act:MultiHandleSliderExtender>
```

Rather than specifying 1600 to 1680, the slider should snap to specific step values like 1600, 1630, 1640, 1645, 1650, 1656 and so on upto 1680. Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I answered a (kind of) similar question about the slightly older `SliderExtender` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7375763/861565) if that helps at all.  I also re-tagged this with javascript, as that's most likely how you would accomplish this task.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I checked your earlier post but what I am looking for is to add only specific values without any increments/steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code `Steps=""` to your MultiHandleSliderExtender?

How many steps you add to the slider changes how much the handles snap down the rail.

Hope this helps.

```
<act:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="mseTimeline" runat="server" BoundControlID="lblSlider"
        Minimum="1600" Maximum="1680" Steps="6" TooltipText="Slide across timeline"
        TargetControlID="ebSlider" Decimals="0"
        RaiseChangeOnlyOnMouseUp="true" OnClientDragEnd="scrollToYear">
    </act:MultiHandleSliderExtender>
```

Comment: Oops, sorry. Just seen your previous comment about wanting specific values not steps.